# find the gradient direction at a point in a shape

Tags: matlab, gradient, hough-transform

I am trying to implement the generalized Hough transform in matlab. The algorithm requires the gradient direction at each point in the shape. How can I measure phi  as shown in the figure below?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the (x,y)-coordinaes of each point on the shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal to the curve [x(t), y(t)] is [-dy(t)/dt, dx(t)/dt]. Thus, with `x` being the x-coordinates and `y` the y-coordinates, the normals are

```
[-diff(y(:)),diff(x(:))]
```

and the angle phi is

```
atan2(diff(x(:)),-diff(y(:)))
```

Comment: the output of for the angle phi is either pi or 0. Doesn't seem to give a true gradient.